# Pro Tools stems export

Tags: sound-design, pro-tools, post-production, stems, export

How can I export clips as files but with all the effects and automation used on them? I can bounce them but there are over 40 channels and wouldn't have time to bounce them all one by one.

Comment: What version of protools are you on?  You can do offline bounces of multiple outputs at once on 11 or 12.

Comment: I'm using 10... Is there maybe an option to render tracks individually with all the processing and then export them all as files...

Answer (score 4):

Route the output of each track to another empty track. Record arm the destination tracks and then hit record. When the record pass is done all your effects and automation will be "printed" to the new tracks.

Comment: Thats going to be your best way on PT10 as long as you don't have master buss processing.